# D3 v4 (Tree Diagram) - Dynamically calculate the height of the SVG given dynamic number of nodes

Tags: d3.js, svg

I dynamically am changing the data for a Tree Diagram, and don't know what the height of the SVG should be. How can I calculate the height of the Tree Diagram to update the SVG dimensions?

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/intelligence_ai/guesukv6/

Please view the code on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/intelligence_ai/guesukv6/), SO requires that I post some code with fiddle links:

```
var treemap = d3.tree().nodeSize([40, 40]);

root = d3.hierarchy(data, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = 100;
root.y0 = 0;
function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var data = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = data.descendants(),
      links = data.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  let connectorLength = 200; // the length of the lines in pixels
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * connectorLength});

nodes = nodes.filter(function(d){
return d.depth != 0;
})
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you specified that the `nodeSize` is `[40,40]` and you have 129 nodes, the height should be:

```
var height = 40 * 129;
```

Since you want to calculate it **dynamically**, it should be:

```
var height = treemap.nodeSize()[1] * nodes.length;
```

Also, when specifying `tree.nodeSize` the root node will be positioned at `0,0`. Therefore, you have to translate the main group:

```
.attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + "," + (height/2) + ")");
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jxw0Ld3c/